# React selectively not passing new props to rendered object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a multi-stage form that gets some intermediate data via AJAX based on [this guide](http://viget.com/extend/building-a-multi-step-registration-form-with-react). I'm having an odd issue where React isn't passing new props to a component.

```
// MyForm.js.jsx
var MyForm = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        switch(this.state.stage) {
            case 1:
                return <InitialFields 
                            nextStage={this.nextStage}
                            save={this.save}
                        />
            case 2:
                return <ChoiceFields 
                            title="Choose first thing:"
                            field="first_id"
                            options={this.state.firstChoices}
                            nextStage={this.nextStage}
                            save={this.save}
                        />
            case 3:
                return <ChoiceFields 
                            title="Choose second thing:"
                            field="second_id"
                            options={this.state.secondChoices}
                            nextStage={this.nextStage}
                            save={this.save}
                       />
         }
    }
// etc ...
});
```

ChoiceFields.js.jsx:

```
var ChoiceFields = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.state);
        var options = this.setOptions();
        return (
            <div className="choiceFields"> 
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1> 
                <SearchBar onChange={this.onSearch} /> 
                <div className="btn-group">{options}</div> 
                <NextButton next={this.saveAndContinue} text="Set Default Values" />
            </div>
        );
    },

    setOptions: function() {
        var buttons = this.state.options;

        return buttons.map(function(choice) {
            return (
                <ChoiceButton key={choice.id} title={choice.name} 
                    description={choice.description} id={choice.id}
                    makeSelection={this.selectButton} selected={choice.selected}
                />
            );
        }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

When the state advances from 1 to 2, it renders the ChoiceFields without issue. When the state advances from 2 to 3, it renders the new title, but the `options` prop remains unchanged despite giving it a different object.

Is there some way to force React to update the prop, or otherwise rerender the `ChoiceFields` object?

--UPDATE--

I was copying `this.props.options` into `this.state.options`, and using state to keep track of whether or not an option was selected. Per @superfell's recommendation, I kept the object array in `props` and calculated which one was selected in the render method. This fixed it the issue.

Comment: can you post the source for the ChoiceFields component

Comment: @superfell I added the code for that. thanks!

Comment: is there more code in ChoiceFields somewhere? its looking at this.state.options, but nothing is setting that, seems like the setOptions function should be working from this.props.options

Comment: `getInitialState` copies the `this.props.options` array into `this.state.options`. After they're added in, I'm adding a `selected` attribute to each object in the array, which keeps track of which object gets rendered as selected. I'm going to test whether or not leaving the object in props works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, you are copying the props to state in your ChoiceFields component in getInitialState. getInitialState doesn't get called again when the props are updated, and so you're left looking at stale state. You can add a [componentWillReceiveProps](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) function to ChoiceFields that can update state from the new props. Or you can refactor to not copy props to state at all, as that is a specific [anti-pattern called out by React](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another option available to you is to give your `ChoiceField` variants different keys, so React will know they're different instances and they'll each get the full component lifecycle when you swap between them on subsequent renders:

```
        case 2:
            return <ChoiceFields 
                        key="first"
                        title="Choose first thing:"
                        field="first_id"
                        options={this.state.firstChoices}
                        nextStage={this.nextStage}
                        save={this.save}
                    />
        case 3:
            return <ChoiceFields 
                        key="second"
                        title="Choose second thing:"
                        field="second_id"
                        options={this.state.secondChoices}
                        nextStage={this.nextStage}
                        save={this.save}
                   />
```

[React.js and Dynamic Children - Why the Keys are Important](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/react-dot-js-and-dynamic-children-why-the-keys-are-important/) has a good explaination of what's happening and links to the relevant docs.